# ASP.Net Development Server not showing up to date representation of the site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-development-serv

I was creating my new webforms application and testing it. Now I added a new textbox to the form and when pressing F5 to test, it doesn't show. None of the changes show when I try to test it.

What's gone wrong?

Comment: Is your development server different than the machine you are writing your code on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press F5 it loads a certain page. Not necessarily the page you were working on.
You can right click the page you were working on in the project explorer of visual studio and select 'set as start page'.

Is this your first web app or have you made previously working apps?